# Freeing a temp node from a linked list

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I have the following function for removing a node from a linked list at a specified position:

```
void deleteNodeAt(node *head, int pos) {
    if(head==NULL)
        return;
    node *temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
    int index=0;
    
    while(head!=NULL) {
        if(index==pos-1)
            temp=head;

        if(index==pos) {
            temp->next=head->next;
            head=head->next;
            
            free(temp);
            temp=NULL;
        }   
        else
            head=head->next;

        index++;
    }
}
```

It works fine if I don't try to free the temp node or if I set it to NULL, but calling free (temp) will break the function. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you allocate memory if you want to _delete_ a node??

Answer (score 0):

First I don't understand why you do a `malloc` in code that is supposed to free a node.

Further you are freeing the wrong node. The node you wanted to free is `head` - it's **not** `temp`.

Try like:

```
void deleteNodeAt(node *head, int pos)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return;

    node *temp;
    int index=0;

    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        if(index==pos-1)
            temp=head;

        if(index==pos)
        {
            temp->next=head->next;
       
            free(head);
          
            // Done - the node has been free'd so just return
            return;
        }   

        head=head->next;
        index++;
    }
}
```

However, there is still a problem.

Consider this:

> What will happen when pos is zero (i.e. when you try to remove the current `head`

Answer: You will use an uninitialized `temp`. That's bad. Further, how will the caller know that `head` has changed? You need some extra code for handling this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pos starts at 0 for the head of the list, you need to pass a pointer to head in order to delete pos 0.  After the call, the head will have changed, so any other pointer to the list would be invalid.

```
#define START_OF_LIST  0
void deleteNodeAt(node **phead, int pos)
{
  if (pos < START_OF_LIST || !*phead)
      return;   /* bad pos or empty list, always check input */
  node *prev = *phead;
  if (pos == START_OF_LIST) {
     /* special case - delete head of list */
     *phead = (*phead)->next;
     free(prev);
     return;
  }
  while (1) {
    node * temp = prev->next;
    if (!temp)  /* Not enough elements in list */
        return;
    pos--;
    if(pos == START_OF_LIST) {
       prev->next = temp->next;  /* unlink temp */
       free(temp);
       return;
    }
    prev = temp;  /* On to the next! */
  }
}
```